# Как правильно получить координаты google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api

Есть такой выпадающий список мест для поля ввода [autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) все работает но у меня нет карты, а мне нужно получить просто координаты выбранного места

```
 var input = document.getElementsByClassName('Profile_address');
 var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input[0]);
 searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
       var places = searchBox.getPlaces();


   places.forEach(function(place) {

  var lat = place.geometry.location.K;
  var lng = place.geometry.location.G;
    $("#Profile_lat").val(lng);
    $("#Profile_lng").val(lat);
   });
});
```

Вот так пытался получить, но это работает не стабильно, может есть более надежный способ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я делаю следующим образом

поле ввода

```
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location">
```

код javascript

```
function initialize() {
        var address = (document.getElementById('pac-input'));
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(address);
        autocomplete.setTypes(['geocode']);
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            if (!place.geometry) {
                return;
            }
        });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

таким образом в переменных place.geometry.location.lat() и place.geometry.location.lat() у вас находятся ваши координаты. Если нужно могу выложить полную вьювку.

Comment: Спасибо, это то что нужно